# how to set the position of image in matlab

Tags: matlab

i am new in matlab and making some practice . I  have drawn this black box. i want to move or change position of  this box. for example moving to right or moving up or down and so on.

[image]

my code:

```
function im = i(r,c)
%UNTITLED9 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
Blk_blk= zeros(r,c);
k=imshow(Blk_blk);
%j= imresize(k,100);

xl = get(Blk_blk, -10);   %for position x way
yl = get(Blk_blk, -10);   % for position y way

set(Blk_blk, -10, xl, -10, yl);
end
```

please specify me if i am using wrong approach in specifying the positioning in x,y (that is x and y )
thanks in advance

Comment: `Blk_blk` is the name of a matrix; the first argument of `set` and `get` should be a handle to an object. The practical implication is that, in the last three lines of your code, `k` should be substituted for `Blk_blk`. However, you will still get an error because of syntax. You will have to look up `set` and `get` in the documentation.

Comment: Also, look up the command `gca` (stands for "get current axes"). It is likely more relevant than `k` to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: cant understand properly even after applying "gca". ???

Comment: xl = get(gca, -10);   %for position x way
yl = get(gca, -10);   % for position y way

set(gca, -10, xl, -10, yl);   is that you are saying?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

Up to this point in your code

```
r = 10;
c = 10;
k = imshow(zeros(r, c));
```

you get

[image]

and after you execute the commands

```
llc_dx = 0.2;
llc_dy = 0.1;
set(gca, 'Position', get(gca, 'Position') + [llc_dx llc_dy 0 0])
```

you get

[image]

Comment: thanks but this taking only decimal  but not 1,3 or 10 and so on??

Comment: You can use integers too. I had to use small values so that the image stays visible.

Comment: but with integer picture does not comes. any idea.even i converted but stils same